# How to run a jar file from the open jdk docker image

Tags: java, docker

I am trying to containerise an application using docker and the official openjdk image. From GitHub: https://github.com/jactor-rises/jactor-persistence/tree/feature-docker

I am trying to simulate the following jar command:

```
java -jar target/jactor-persistence-1.2.1-SNAPSHOT-app.jar
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:13

LABEL jactor-rises="https://github.com/jactor-rises" \
      email="..."

COPY target/jactor-persistence-*-app.jar /usr/src/myapp/app.jar
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
EXPOSE 1099

CMD [ "java -jar app.jar" ]
```

Comment: Remove the brackets and quotes from the `CMD` line: `CMD java -jar app.jar`.  If that doesn't help, can you edit the question to add the actual `docker run` command you're using, and the error message it prints out?

Comment: what's your question? do you face any error?

Comment: The _exec_ form of CMD instruction needs a comma-separated list of single quoted items, [like shown in the Docker reference docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd). The _shell_ form of the instruction is given in the accepted answer, and has implications for using alternate arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application runs fine by changing the `CMD` line suggested by [David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze) in his comment

```
CMD java -jar app.jar
```

No build error throw me off and I did not consider that this was a possible cause of the error...